# How to use first word of UITableView result as an alias to name sections

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to find a way to name a section, and add results to that section in a UITableView based on the first 3 characters in the Cell Name.

example:

In my cells I have report names that look like this

- Occupiers Statement 2013
- Annual 2013
- Certificate of Maintenance 2012
- POT Dec 2012
- Audit Mar 2011

For these reports, I need to use the first word as an alias so I can create and name sections, as in POT would actually name to Path Of Travel and Annual would name as Annual Passive

I have seen info on naming using first letter but I cannot find any info on naming using alias

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. I'm not completely clear how you exactly want to group them, however if you follow tutorial like [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/12/10/implementing-uitableview-sections-from-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects/), you should be able to get a better idea.

Comment: Thanks Enrico. I appreciate your help. I'll start reading :-)

Comment: Just to see if I get that tutorial  properly, substringToIndex is the part of the code I need? So potentially I could take say the first 3 characters by using substringToIndex 3 for example....is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. I think you might potentially be able to use that code with very little modification.